# How to change text color in tableView section in swift

Tags: ios, swift

how to change a textcolor of section in tableview in swift.

viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: You will find the manuals useful! SO is not Google by proxy. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/textColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, viewForHeaderInSection   section: Int) -> UIView! {


var customView:UIView?
customView.frame = // set frame according to tableview width and header height
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
return customView
}
```

Hope this will help you.