# How to change the color of text in a tableview swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've created a tableview in swift and I'm customising appearance to make it look nicer. I'd like to change the appearance to have a clear background and white text color. Tableview function:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTableView
        .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    let score = scores[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = String(score.gameScore!)
    UITableViewCell.appearance().textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();

    return cell;
}
```

So the second part works with the clear cells but but the first part doesn't for some reason. I checked out some sources online but can't seem to get this one right:

[How to change text color in tableView section in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30524387/how-to-change-text-color-in-tableview-section-in-swift)

https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-change-uitableviewcell-selection-color-app-wide/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't think it's wise to use `appearance()` to globally alter all your cells, but if you do it, you should be, as your link says, calling it in your `AppDelegate`, not each time you load a cell.

Second, you can customize many of these features directly in storyboard (and since you're using a reusable cell, you really should) - go find your cell and change the text color there.

Or, as mentioned by @Umair, you can simply change that call to not be global, and change the color directly.

Answer (score 10):

You need to change the color of text using the "cell" object you created. So it should be like this

```
cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```

Change it to any color of your desire

Answer (score 3):

Just change in your table view code, like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Categoria")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = categoris[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white // <- Changed color here
    return cell!
}
```